# Show picture in 30 days ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to make my first public .net website but I have a little problem.
It's a webshop, where i want to show at new product picture, if the product is not older than the current date with more than 30 days?

Markup:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server">        
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" class="tblSales">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>' runat="server" /></h3>
                        <h2>
              <a  href='<%# "Products.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ProductID") %>'>Read More</a></h2>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <h4>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%#Eval("ProductPrice")%>' runat="server" />,-</h4>      
                            <div> 
<img alt="New product" src="images/NewProduct.png" /><!--This picture should show in 30 days-->
                              </div> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <hr />
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class sale : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ProductsTableAdapter p = new ProductsTableAdapter();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }

    protected void GetData()
    {
        rptProducts = p.GetProductsByCategoryID(3);
        rptProducts();        
    }
}
```

Comment: im confused, would you explain it again in precise.. what i understood is, you have to show a picture which not older than current date ? but what's with 30 days

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.... is this not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED: As a user noted this may be a misinterpretation so...

IF you want to filter items that were added and not display them at all use the following LINQ expression on the GetData method:

```
rptProducts = p.GetProductsByCategoryID(3).Where(p=>p.ProductAddedDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30));
```

you need to have a property  (in the above example I added a DateTime ProductAddedDate to the product class

IF you want to not show the image based on the date BUT show everything else you could:

In the ItemDataBound event of the repeater you can set asp control (replace static html  with asp:Image which allows you to control display using the Visible property i.e.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptProducts_Databound">        
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" class="tblSales">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>' runat="server" /></h3>
                        <h2>
              <a  href='<%# "Products.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ProductID") %>'>Read More</a></h2>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <h4>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%#Eval("ProductPrice")%>' runat="server" />,-</h4>      
                            <div> 
<asp:Image ID="ProdImg" runat="server" AlternativeText="New product" ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/" + Eval("ImageFileName")' Visible="True"/><!--This picture should show in 30 days-->
                              </div> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <hr />
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CS codebehind

```
protected void rptProducts_Databound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var imgCtrl = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("ProdImg");
    var dataItem = (Product)e.Item.DataItem;
    imCtrl.Visible = dataItem.ProductAddedDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers Jeppe's question. If I read the question correctly, he wants to show all the products (in a given category), but only show the NewProduct-icon next to the products that are not older than 30 days. Your code just removes all products that are not older than 30 days.

Comment: Amended to include additional method for conditional asp:Image. This should cover all bases

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, I find out how to make it :)thanks to you, quite simple but i works.
here is the code I made:

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="~/images/new.png" Visible='<%#GetProductSalesPic(Eval("ProductDate"))%>' runat="server" />
```

C# code:

```
protected bool GetProductSalesPic(object Date)
    {
        DateTime actDate = (DateTime)Date;
        if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) < actDate)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

And again, Thanks You, for the fast and good response :D

Comment: :) I was also going to post the 'call a code behind method using Eval as parameter' but thought 2 examples was enough :) well done though